# UWP Debugging with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: debugging, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am having trouble debugging UWP applications with VS 2017 (Update 2). I can usually debug the app several times, then I will try debugging and get the "deploy succeeded" message, but the app does not load. I can close VS and restart and then debug a few more times. I have this happening on both of my major UWP projects and with a few of the UWP sample applications. Basically, since moving to VS 2017 I've had this multiple debug session issues.

Anyone else run across this, or perhaps know of a work around? (besides closing/opening VS...)

Thanks.

Comment: Try repairing Visual Studio, I have never hit this issue.

Comment: Tried this already. I have this happening on two systems, multiple projects. Including some of the sample UWP applications from MS.

Comment: What are the windows OS version for the two systems? Is your Visual Studio 2017 version 15.2(26430.12)?